# Update flat list item onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

How to update item text in `flatlist` item `onpress`?

```
renderEntries({ item, index }) {
    return(
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> this.setState({value: this.state.value+1})>
             <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )
}
```

i get this error:

[image]

Comment: error shown : this.setState is not a function.

Comment: can you show the code, from where you are calling `renderEntries` function?

Comment: <FlatList
     ref={(ref) => { this.list = ref; }}
     keyExtractor={(item) => item.entry.entryId}
     data={this.state.data}
     renderItem={this.renderEntries}
     horizontal={false}
 />

Comment: use this: `renderItem={this.renderEntries.bind(this)}` bind that method like this or in `constructor`, like this `this.renderEntries = this.renderEntries.bind(this)`.

Comment: you could also define it like this: `renderEntries = ({item, index}) => {...}`, no need for `bind`

Comment: @thedude that is the another way of `binding` only by using `arrow function`.

Comment: @shalonteoh binding is required to `bind` the `context` of `react` component, if you don't `bind` it then `this` keyword (refer to **react class**) will not be present inside that method, since you are using `this.setState`, `binding` is required otherwise you can ignore the `binding`, to check that just remove `this.setState` inside that method it will not throw the error.

Comment: You can read more about binding in react here - http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/

Comment: thank you guys for the info :-) but the text value in <text> still not updated. the state did updated but the flatlist not re-render. how to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

I recently had the same problem following Solution worked for me

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  SectionList,
  Text,
  NativeModules,
  Button,
  FlatList,
  Switch,
  View
} from 'react-native';


export default class alarm extends Component {

  state={
    data:[
      { name:'First' , isOn:true },
      { name:'Second', isOn:true },
      { name:'Third' , isOn:true },
      { name:'Fourth' , isOn:false }
    ],
    selected:true,
  }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.name;

  _onValueChanged = (item,value) => 
  {    
      var items = this.state.data;
      var index = items.indexOf(item);
      items[index].isOn = value;
      this.setState({data:items});
      this.setState({selected:!this.state.selected});  
  };

  _renderItem = ({item}) => 
  (    
    <View>  
        <Text>{ item.name }</Text>
        <Switch value={item.isOn}  
        onValueChange={(value) =>
        {        
         this._onValueChanged(item,value);
        }}/>
    </View>
  )

  render() {
    return (

       <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          extraData={this.state.selected}  // This is the Key you need to privde extra data parmater
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        />

    );
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('alarm', () => alarm);
```